# python inserting single quotes (') around MySQL table name

Tags: python, mysql

I have a database called project1 with the following tables:

```
_systbl1
_systbl2
_systbl3
dataset1
dataset2
dataset3
```

MySQL user odbc will need to be granted SELECT permissions on dataset% tables whenever a new one is added.

To accomplish this, I'm using a simple python script, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="user",
    passwd="pass",
    db="project1"
    )

    # Create Cursor Object
cur = db.cursor()

# get list of tables beginning with dataset
cur.execute("SHOW TABLES FROM project1 LIKE 'dataset%';")

# run GRANT statement for each table
for row in cur.fetchall() :
    cur.execute("GRANT SELECT ON `project1`.`%s` TO `odbc`@`localhost`;", row)
    cur.execute("GRANT SELECT ON `project1`.`%s` TO `odbc`@`%`;", row)
```

Unfortunately, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysql_query.py", line 20, in <module>
    cur.execute("GRANT SELECT ON `project1`.`%s` TO `odbc`@`localhost`;", row)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'project1.'dataset1'' doesn't exist")
```

As you can see in the last line of the error, the problem is that python is putting a single quote around the table names when generating the query.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use SQL parameters for table names. SQL parameters are escaped by the database adapter to not be interpreted as anything but literal values.

You'll have to interpolate those yourself instead, but *be absolutely certain* that your table name does not hold untrusted data (prevent SQL injection attacks):

```
cur.execute("GRANT SELECT ON `project1`.`%s` TO `odbc`@`localhost`;" % row)
cur.execute("GRANT SELECT ON `project1`.`%s` TO `odbc`@`%%`;" % row)
```

(where the `%` character in the grant has been escaped by doubling it to `%%`).

Comment: Thanks, that works for the top line, however on the second line I get
`
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "mysql_query.py", line 21, in <module>
        cur.execute("GRANT SELECT ON `project1`.`%s` TO `odbc`@`%`;" % row)
    TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
`
possibly due to there being a % in the query?

Comment: @ivorytux: indeed, you need to double that one. Sorry about that!

Comment: oops, my mistake. You had it rigth all along, I just missed the second % Thanks again Martinj!

Answer (score 1):

Instead use:

```
cur.execute("GRANT SELECT ON `project`.`%s` TO `odbc`@`localhost`" % row)
```

This will not use the normal escaping of the input.  Beware of a backtick in any of your table names, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
sql = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `""" + project +  """` ( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`id`))"""
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.